# What is the reason for the occurence of a segmentation fault in this case, when I assign pointer in a function

Tags: c, pointers, memory

This is the code here:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void assign (int *a1, int *a2) {
    a1 = a2;
}
int main() {
    int *a; int b; int *c; int d;
    b = d = 5;
    a = &b;
    printf("%d", *a);
    assign(c, &d);
    printf("\n%d", *c);
    return 0;
}
```

It's fine when I assign pointers manually in the main() function, but the segmentation fault appears when I assign it in the function. Why is this so?

Comment: `a1` and `a2` are local variable in assign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `assign` has no effect.  All it's doing is performing a local assignment which has no effect on the caller.  As a result, `c` is undefined in `main` and you get a segmentation fault.

In order for `assign` to do what you intend, you have to pass it the address of `c`, then do a pointer assignment in `assign`.

Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void assign (int **a1, int *a2) {
    *a1 = a2;
}

int main() {
    int *a; int b; int *c; int d;
    b = d = 5;

    a = &b;
    printf("%d\n", *a);

    assign(&c, &d);
    printf("%d\n", *c);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
5
5
```

I also moved the newlines to the end of the format strings, which is the normal place to put them.

Comment: In the assign function, instead of *a1 = a2, if I give a1 = &a2, why do I get a segfault?

Comment: @Jatinshravan I think you need to read on 'pass by value' and 'pass by reference'. Changing `a1` from `assign` will *not* affect `c` in `main`.

Comment: Assigning to `a1` has no effect on the caller.  `a1` is strictly local to `assign`.

Answer (score 2):

`c` is passed by value into the function `assign`. This means that modifying `a1` from the function will not affect `c`.

To get the expected results, pass `c` by reference, i.e, pass the address of `c`:

```
assign(&c, &d);
```

and make slight modifications to the function:

```
void assign (int **a1, int *a2) {
    *a1 = a2;
}
```

and you are good to go! :-)

Comment: In this answer, why do I get a segfault when I do the following:

a1 = &a2 in the assign function

Answer (score 1):

Arguments are passed by value in C, so modyfying `a1` in `assign()` won't affect `c` in `main()`.

`c` remains uninitialized and it has automatic storage duration, so its value is indeterminate.

Then, you used this inderminate value in `printf("\n%d", *c);`.
This invokes *undefined behavor* and the program just **happened** to cause segmentation fault.